# error enabling and disabling constraints on postgresql 9.3.5

Tags: postgresql-9.3

i have a requirement involving a bulk loading data in a postgresql 9.3.5 running on a centos6.5 machine. The idea is to disable the constraints before the bulk loading and enable again when data loading is done. I have no problem disabling the constraints, the problem happens when i try to enable again.

the sql commands that i use to disable constraints:

```
alter table myTableA drop constraint myTableA_id_fkey cascade;
alter table myTableB drop constraint myTableB_id_fkey cascade;
alter table myTableC drop constraint myTableC_id_fkey cascade;
```

the sql commands that i want to use to enable constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE myTableA ADD CONSTRAINT myTableA_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE myTableB ADD CONSTRAINT myTableB_id_fkey;
ALTER TABLE myTableC ADD CONSTRAINT myTableC_id_fkey;
```

But when i try to launch the enabling constraints, i recieve this:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
```

LINE 1: ...oor_element ADD CONSTRAINT myTableA_id_fkey;

sources:

What do i am doing wrong?

Another question, is it a good idea to do this every time that database is loaded using this way? It is suposed to be that this a bulk loading executed once a day.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-altertable.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't enabling/disabling constraints. You're dropping and re-creating them. When re-creating them you must define them again, because the database discarded its knowledge of them when you told it to.

Perhaps you meant to disable, rather than drop, the constraints?

If so: You can't do that. There's no `DISABLE CONSTRAINTS` option or anything like that.

As a result, probably the best way to go until PostgreSQL offers a proper way to temporarily disable constraints for data loading is to drop and re-create your constraints each time.

To do that, you must use proper, complete `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...` commands with full constraint definitions.

---

(The following risks creating undetectable and invalid FK violations. Do not do this unless you're really, really sure you need to, instead just drop and re-create the constraints as above.)

What you *can* do for foreign key constraints, though it's not a great idea, is:

- Disable the system triggers that implement the constraint checks using `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER ALL`
- Do your work
- Re-enable the foreign key constraint triggers using `ALTER TABLE .. ENABLE TRIGGER ALL`

Note that this is very heavy-handed, only affects `FOREIGN KEY` constraints (not `CHECK`, `NOT NULL`, `EXCLUSION`, `PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE` etc constraints) and is generally ugly.

Most importantly, this never validates that the constraint is actually correct, but you can do so with an additional hack: marking each constraint as `NOT VALID` in the catalogs then re-validating it with `VALIDATE CONSTRAINT`. PostgreSQL doesn't offer a public and supported way to mark an existing FK constraint as `NOT VALID`, so there's no properly safe way to do this.

---

Ideally PostgreSQL would allow foreign key check constraints to be `FOR EACH STATEMENT` and `DEFERRABLE`, so you could just defer them until commit. That doesn't help currently though, because they still have to run one check for each row, there's no saving for doing it in bulk. If PostgreSQL gets support for virtual tables of changed tuples in statement-level triggers at some point (as has been discussed on pgsql-hackers recently) this might be possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You can't, really. You can only disable the trigger, do your work, re-enable the trigger, then re-validate. Which I'm adding as an edit, I just had to confirm it was still correct first.